# Galaxy S3 Mini drains excessive battery when Wifi is ON

Tags: wi-fi, battery-life, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

This question is linked to this one: [Wifi battery saving tips or automation](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/45556/wifi-battery-saving-tips-or-automation/45566?noredirect=1#45566)

This time, the question is different.

I have here a Galaxy S3 Mini phone that behaves strange. When Wifi is OFF, battery takes a lot of time to drain. When Wifi is ON, battery takes up to 4 hours to drain.

I have a personal Galaxy S3 "Large". As we all know, wifi increases power consumption. But not at that crazy level. My S3 consumed little less than 40% its battery power when the other phone was at 15% of remaining charge.

The battery monitor indicates that "Android operating system" takes 67% of the consumed power with a high CPU usage. When wifi is disabled that does not happen. The phone is rooted. ROM is I810NXXALL6, version 4.1.2. At the current time I don't remember exactly how I rooted this phone, but I can remember I flashed a stock no brand ROM.

I would like to ask if this behaviour:

1. May have been caused by hardware damaged (which means phone is to unroot, de-odin and send to repair)
2. If I could flash something (e.g. a radio ROM) to improve wifi performance

Comment: When wifi is on: is it actually connecting to a wifi network or is it simply searching for a network?

Comment: Both cases. It's difficult for me to tell whether the battery drains faster when home (connected) or out of home (searching)